# conda not working even though conda is found in site-packages

Tags: anaconda, conda

I encountered a problem with conda while setting up an environment for tensorflow.
I did a whole bunch of conda install and upgrade, updates. After all this, I quite command prompt (Windows 10 OS) and after a few days, return to find that I could not use some conda command such as update, info etc.

I went to look into the site-packages and everything is there so I am puzzled by this strange behavior. I went to uninstall conda and install using pip but that just screwed conda up even more. Now I cannot use conda and I cant get into my environment.

Is there any quick fix or a reinstallation of anaconda is required?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Without actual error messages, or the steps you went through, it is impossible to say. Reinstallation is probably the most straightforward solution

Comment: Did a reinstalling of anaconda and everything went back to normal. Had to be caution when to use conda or pip within virtual enviroment in anaconda.

Comment: Always use conda :-)